# javascript check if object implements HTMLAnchorElement interface

Tags: javascript, dom, interface, anchor

Is there a javascript way of determining if an object implements the 'HTMLAnchorElement' interface?  When I do `typeOf(someVariable)` it returns `'object'`. Can I take that a step further and verify the type implements the 'HTMLAnchorElement' interface?  Seems like it would be simple enough but I can't find any examples.  Any help or sample code would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator.

Example:

```
var a = document.links[0];
alert(a instanceof HTMLAnchorElement); // true if there's a link in the document
```

Note that IE7- doesn't define the `HTMLAnchorElement` object. As a fallback, you can check for the `tagName` or `nodeName` property of a supposed element.

Comment: lol yes I thought of this when I went to lunch. Sometimes a break is all we need. Thanks so much for the response.